# Popen.write - operation on closed file | images to video using FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a video file from images from my webcam(using SimpleCV), the images are converted to PIL format and then tostring() [rawformat]

I'm using python subprocess and Popen to create the video using the FFmpeg.

I can pipe the one image to the FFmpeg and make a video out of it
But when I try to do a bunch of them I get a error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

here's my code.

```
import subprocess as sp
from SimpleCV import *
from Image import Image

FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe"

img = Camera().getImage().toRGB()


command = [FFMPEG_BIN, '-y',  # (optional) overwrite output file if it exists
           '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-s', '%sx%s'%(img.width,img.height),  # size of one frame
           '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', '-r', '24',  # frames per second
           '-i', '-',  # The imput comes from a pipe
           '-an',  # Tells FFMPEG not to expect any audio
           '-vcodec', 'libx264rgb',
           'my_output_videofile.mp4']


pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE)#, stderr=sp.PIPE)


for n in xrange(10):
    img = Camera().getImage().toRGB().getPIL().tostring()
    pipe.stdin.write(img)


pipe.terminate()
```

It's wierd because the pipe.terminate() is in the end of the code, and it should close the file right away.

EDIT:
Removed the stderr

```
  ffmpeg version N-63208-gbe1fbc0 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 17 2014 01:30:26 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib 
  --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray 
  --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug 
  --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus 
  --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame 
  --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx 
  --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid 
  --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 83.100 / 52. 83.100
  libavcodec     55. 62.100 / 55. 62.100
  libavformat    55. 38.100 / 55. 38.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 44236 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 320x240, 44236 kb/s, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
No pixel format specified, rgb24 for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264rgb @ 0000000000359de0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264rgb @ 0000000000359de0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 1.3, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264rgb @ 0000000000359de0] 264 - core 142 r2431 ac76440 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - 
http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 
psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 
chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 
constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 
keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 
qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'my_output_videofile.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.38.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264rgb) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), rgb24, 320x240, q=-1--1, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> libx264rgb)
frame=    7 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
```

Comment: Please drop the `, stderr=sp.PIPE` argument, and copy-paste the full console output of your program, including the full Python exception and the traceback, and the messages printed by ffmpeg. Also indicate the Python version you are using.

Comment: What happens if you modify your Python script to write the input image data to a temporary file, and then run `ffmpeg.exe` manually on that file?

Comment: This is more info what we have before, but still not enough, especially about the full console output, and writing to a temporary file first.

Comment: I don't know how to use FFmpeg manually, I got this script from here http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/, I'm trying to adapt it to work with feed images from the camera.

Comment: I wonder if I have to specify to jump to the next frame or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel so stupid...

SimpleCV has an easy to use function that does exactly what I'm looking for.

For anyone interested.

http://simplecv.org/docs/SimpleCV.html#i/SimpleCV.Stream.VideoStream

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the *ffmpeg* process dies before it can receive all the images you are trying to add in the loop. If you drop the `, stderr=sp.PIPE` argument, you can see the error message printed by *ffmpeg*.